# HBase : how to design this rowkey?

Tags: hbase

I have a large number of data to store into HBase. It's basically csv file containing product information :

```
date|product_id|client_id|client_name
2020-08-02|152341|1|Tom
2020-08-02|152341|2|Kate
```

The user should be able to retrieve a list of product info by `(date, product_id)` (which should be API parameters).
**(date, product_id) is not unique**.

In this case, how do I design the rowkey in HBase ?

As `(date, product_id)` is not unique, I must add a UUID to it when inserting data into HBase. So it will look like this : `2020-08-02_152341_[UUID]`. It will work fine, but in this case there will be hotspot problem.

But if I add salt/hash like `01-2020-08-02_152341_[UUID]`, how can I know what the UUID is ? It's not part of user input. So I can neither use startKey/endKey (as there is salt) nor reconstruct the rowkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both. Here is how:

- To avoid hotspots, **prepend** to row key a hash of `date` and `product_id` (**not** UUID!). A simple hashing function such as [murmur](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.google.common.hash.Hashing/murmur3_128) should do.
- Since combination of `date` and `product_id` is **not** unique, you need to also **append** a value to your row key. This can be UUID. But, *if possible*, append it with a value of an existing attribute in your domain model *if unique*. (I see `"1|Tom"` as a record. Is that `"1"` unique?)

While accessing records from HBase, read rows by 'prefix filter'. In this case, your prefix would be:

```java
hash(date + "_" + product_id) + "_"+ date + "_" + product_id + "_"
```

See [setRowPrefixFilter](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan/setRowPrefixFilter) for how to fetch by prefix. Alternatively, you may consider using a library such as [hbase-orm](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/hbase-orm) to fetch records by prefix in an object oriented way (**Disclosure**: I'm the author of the library).